# Can't resolve "Cannot create DbSet for 'OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreApplication" because this type is not included in the model for the context."

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, openiddict

I'm using the authorization code flow with the OpenIddict library and I'm getting an "*InvalidOperationException*" with the following message: "**Cannot create DbSet for 'OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreApplication' because this type is not included in the model for the context.**" message. This message is thrown when trying to run the application.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX5S5.png)

I've found some solutions online, although none have been able to resolve my issue.

Here's my startup configuration and DbContext.  I'm using the default identity models in ASPNet Core 6.

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()

    // Register the OpenIddict core components.
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        // Configure OpenIddict to use the Entity Framework Core stores and models.
        // Note: call ReplaceDefaultEntities() to replace the default entities.
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
               .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
    })

    // Register the OpenIddict server components.
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        // Enable the client credentials flow.
        options.AllowClientCredentialsFlow();

    // Enable the authorization code flow.
    options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow().RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange();

    // Enable the token endpoint.
    options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
        .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");

    // Register the signing and encryption credentials.
    options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
          .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

    // Register scopes (permissions)
    options.RegisterScopes("api");

    // Register the ASP.NET Core host and configure the ASP.NET Core options.
    options.UseAspNetCore()
          .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
          .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough();
    })

    // Register the OpenIddict validation components.
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        // Import the configuration from the local OpenIddict server instance.
        options.UseLocalServer();

    // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
    options.UseAspNetCore();
    });
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options) {   }
```

I've yet to find why I'm receiving this issue.  Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was within my startup configuration.  I found 2 calls to the following method like so...

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
  options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    options.UseOpenIddict();
});
```

I removed the first method call and the exception went away.